# how to fetch whole string if part of the sting is present in list using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I want to search the following list, to see if any of the string items contain `'aed'`; if so, I want to return the whole string (e.g. `'abc/aed'`). How can this be achieved using python/pyspark?

```py
list=['abc/aed','bcd/eac','rtf/reew','opee/rew']
```

Comment: What do you want to do if that is not found?

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```py
my_list=['abc/aed','bcd/eac','rtf/reew','opee/rew']
output = [val for val in my_list if "aed" in val]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use a list comprehension:

```py
list = ['abc/aed', 'bcd/eac', 'rtf/reew', 'opee/rew']
output = [x for x in list if "aed" in x]
print(output)  # ['abc/aed']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in list:
    if "aed" in i:
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `map` for python list. *e.g.,*

```
>>> l = ['abc/aed','bcd/eac','rtf/reew','opee/rew']
>>> list(map(lambda x: x if x.find("aed") != -1 else False, l))
['abc/aed', False, False, False]
```